# AWS ELB routes differently based on subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

The AWS ELB redirects differently for subdomains (in my specific case it's language subdomains like ko.mydomain.com and es.domain.com).

I'm currently using the "Enable load balancer generated cookie stickiness" option. I understand the reason for this is the cookie it saves is based on the subdomain that is being accessed.

How can I make the stickiness work across subdomains?

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to use the load balancer generated cookies. There is no way to set the domain of the cookie differently than the domain to which the cookie was requested.

Solutions:

1. Generate your own cookie, use that to determine stickyness.
2. Switch to use path based routes instead of subdomains
3. Update your application so that it would not rely on stickyness to function properly.

Comment: In option #1 are you talking about the AWS option "enable application-controlled session stickiness" ? From the AWS docs I wasn't able to understand what I need to implement in my application for that to work. Can you elaborate on path based routes? I'm not familiar with that option.

Comment: Yes, #1 refers to application controlled stickyness. That means your application generates the cookie and you can set the cookie domain to just be the root domain instead of including a subdomain. Then the load balancer will look for and keep track of the cookie to determine which instance it would go to.

Comment: Using path based routes would be putting the locale into the path somewhere and having your application look for that. Something like `/en-US/my-page/`

Comment: Oh, yes I understand what you mean by path based. What exactly does the cookie that my application generates need to include? I expected the AWS docs to include an explanation but really didn't find one. In the AWS interface I mainly setup a name for the application cookie name, but what do I need to do on the application end?

Comment: The cookie needs to be unique, something like a session cookie should work.

Comment: Do you mean like putting the session id in a cookie? So i tell aws the cookie is named myCookie and just put a value inside it of the php session id? No format or something?

Comment: If you are using php, you can simply use the php session cookie, though an easier route may be to use memcached sessions so you don't need sticky sessions in the first place.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is I can tell AWS ELB the cookie name is PHPSESSID and that should work? I'm using memcached sessions, but each instance has it's own memcached, and I'd like to avoid changing that.

Comment: That should work. You may get some weirdness one some requests if the session cookie hasn't yet been established. Switching to a shared memcached instance like elasticcache would be a better route.

Comment: It actually didn't really work, seemed like the whole routing became random when I changed that. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Domain based routing is now supported by AWS ELB. Check [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-host-based-routing-and-increased-rules-on-its-application-load-balancer/).